Phone storage space is less than shown in about phone section
I have Samsung galaxy A73. Same model is written on the phone box and phone storage's about section.
Phone storage is 256GB according to phone box and phone setting.
The Problem is when storage is about to cross 16GB, it shows Storage is Full.
What the problem can be?

Have you installed an 16GB SD-card and formatted it as internal? If yes it will replace your internal storage.

What is shown in the Settings - Battery and device care - Storage (or similar settings)?

How old is the phone? Some devices are faked thus an older device with less memory is modified in a way that hides the real device name and storage size. Try multiple hardware info apps and compare the results regarding phone model, RAM and flash size
